# How can I install a wifi driver for RTL8723BE on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

When I run this command

```
lspci | grep "Wireless\|WiFi"
```

I got this result:

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

How can I install a wifi driver for this chip?

Comment: Why do you need to install a driver for this device? This device is supposed to be supported by default. What exact problem(s) are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/roopansh/rtl8723be_wifi

How to install is explaned in the README.I only hope you can reach the internet.